# How to extract a substring of a URL with regex in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need some help with RegEx. I have a URL:

`article/life/food/woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story/275-88a8538f-4c62-4204-aed8-4381d618208d`

This URL is not fixed and this changes every time. I only need to extract `woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story` and store it in table.

Here's my attempt:

```
select parse_url(c1:uri):path as PATH, 
       count(1) as CNT 
from "OPE_RAW_DATA"."TAGGER_DEFAULT"."INTERACTION_20221107" 
where c1:uri like'%www.kens5.com%'
group by PATH
order by CNT desc
```

Comment: "This URL is not fixed and this changes everytime." How do you know how to parse it then? What characteristic of the part you need to parse out identifies it? Perhaps it's the longest section between slashes that is not hex?

Comment: I am getting this url from database using parse_URL. there are more than 30 url and I am only interested in this part  "woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story " which is basically comes at 3 or 4 position in the URL and this part has more text and explain the title. for example :  I don't need this "article/life/food/"  and I am interested in the "woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story " this has more text info and can contain number.

Comment: Is it always either 3rd or 4th?

Comment: yes, mostly. Its after article/life/food/  or article/sports/nba/spurs/ but usually at 3 or 4 position. The difference is this section contains "-", numbers and content is bigger. As you can see here "woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story" this has almost more than 30 characters, number and "-". this can help i think

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a JavaScript UDF to split the string into an array and find the longest one:

```
create or replace function PARSE_LONGEST_TEXT_PATH(URL string)
returns string
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
    let a = URL.split('/');
    let longest = a.reduce(
        function (a, b) {
            return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
        });
    return longest;
$$;

select parse_longest_text_path
    ('article/life/food/woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story/275-88a8538f-4c62-4204-aed8-4381d618208d');
```

This doesn't handle the case if a the longest string is a hex value, but if you need that I can modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the longest string between 3rd and 4th item, you can use something like this:

```
IFF( length(split(c1,'/')[2]) > length(split(c1,'/')[3]), split(c1,'/')[2], split(c1,'/')[3] )
```

For example:

```
select IFF( length(split(c1,'/')[2]) > length(split(c1,'/')[3]), split(c1,'/')[2], split(c1,'/')[3] )
from values 
('article/life/food/woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story/275-88a8538f-4c62-4204-aed8-4381d618208d'),
('article/life/woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story/275-88a8538f-4c62-4204-aed8-4381d618208d')
tmp(c1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest flattening the url so you have more control over the criteria for parsing the topic.

```
set str='article/life/food/woman-who-called-911-over-pink-bbq-tells-her-side-of-the-story/275-88a8538f-4c62-4204-aed8-4381d618208d';

select distinct 
       url,
       first_value(b.value) over (partition by url order by length(translate(b.value,'0123456789-','')) desc) as topic --pick the one that's longest after removing numbers and hyphens
from (select $str as url) a, 
     lateral split_to_table(url,'/') b
where b.index between 3 and 4 --change as needed
```